# BOT does not calls choiceSelection method defined in PromptDialog.Choice using web-chat v4 framework

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I am having a BOT application which is being developed using Microsoft BOT Framework V3 and WebChat Framework V4. In one of the scenario where user sends a particular utterance say "I want to place an order" which goes to LUIS and then BOT replies users to choose some choice using **PromptDialog.Choice(context,choiceSelection,message)**. E.g. "Home Delivery", "Self Pickup"

Now when user clicks on one of the button (Say "Home Delivery"), then technically the **choiceSelection** method should be invoked but instead of that BOT takes that choice as a new utterances and calls the LUIS to which no intent is mapped and hence the scenario does not complete
with expected result.

Also I have checked with using BOT WebChat V3 version, the scenario works absolutely fine without failing. But due to client requirement, I would like to go with WebChat v4 instead of WebChat v3 framework.

Any suggestions, work around will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to choose from:

1. Limit how and when utterances and selections are captured by LUIS so every response isn't getting processed. Or,
2. Provide a "none" intent. If you supply your training model with sufficient examples for getting correct responses, then unrelated queries *should* map to "none". Really, the emphasis is on "sufficient examples". If you don't supply enough data to train your model with, then you will certainly get undesirable results. Once you get the "none" intent to properly produce, you can set the logic in your bot to recognize "none" was returned and to keep on going.

In truth, both options together would serve you well.

As for Web Chat, it has no bearing on LUIS responses. It is merely a client that receives and returns activities. Out-of-the-box, it does nothing to the activities unless you implement custom components and code.

For clarity, there is no relationship between Botbuilder v3/v4 and BotFramework Web Chat v3/v4. They can be used interchangeably. However, Web Chat v3 (a.k.a. "botchat") is deprecated and should not be used. Web Chat v4 is the platform you will want to use.

Hope of help!